# Comparing three measuring devices, should I analyze the measurements or the resulting regressions?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, correlation, nonlinear, engineering-statistics

**Background**:
The operator has three measuring devices D1, D2, and D3. The devices are all the same make and model. The devices can rapidly measure material property X. The operator ***really*** needs to know material property Y, which is an expensive, time-consuming test. But, using a accurate correlation, the operator can use the device in lieu of the test for Y.

To find the correlation, the operator uses a device to measure X for *n* samples (typically 6-10), then measures property Y for the same *n* samples. With this data, they do a regression analysis between X and Y, and then use the device for the remaining data collection.

**Research question**:
Will measurements with D1, D2, and D3 produce statistically similar regression equations? In other words, can the operator identify one regression equation and apply that to all the devices, or do they need to find unique regression equations for each device?

**Problem**:
To answer my question, should I analyze the measured values from D1, D2, and D3 (*x1*, *x2*, and *x3*) or should I analyze the resulting regression equations (Y=f(X1), Y=f(X2), Y=f(X3))? Which is the stronger analysis...or are the results the same?

At present we are using a non-linear exponential regression, Y=B0*exp(B1*X). In the future, we will reassess if other models are a more appropriate fit (linear, log, and complex micromechanics model).